# What Firefox settings should be changed from factory defaults to ensure privacy vis-à-vis Mozilla?

Tags: privacy, firefox

Besides turning off everything in Edit/Preferences/Advanced/Data Choices and `browser.newtabpage.directory.ping`
`browser.newtabpage.directory.source`
`browser.safebrowsing...`
`security.ssl.errorReporting.enabled`

What should one change in Firefox settings to avoid sending extra info to Mozilla?

Comment: make the executable a symlink to Chrome?

Comment: @schroeder - ie6 - to ensure your browsing doesn't happen at all. :P

Comment: I went for the platform independent option, but, I also agree with you that I'd prefer Mozilla over Google for privacy. The question was about avoiding Mozilla, not privacy in general :)  (*checks overhead for a joke that might ben passing me by*)

Comment: Just `telnet server.com 80`, followed by `GET /some/page HTTP/1.0` and two carriage returns. Parse the html/javascript in your head and respond accordingly. This way you can be sure to only send the relevant data. `</joke>`

Comment: The most secure browser is Tor, based off Mozilla. You can copy its settings. Tor uses the Tor network, a series of NSA-proof proxies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unwise to post link-only answers, yet I'll point interested readers at https://github.com/pyllyukko/user.js. A metric tonne of security- and privacy-related settings are there, waiting to be implemented in your Firefoxes.

I also link to permanent webarchived version of the main script in case the repo gets deleted or lost: https://web.archive.org/web/20150413081702/https://github.com/pyllyukko/user.js/blob/master/user.js

<sub>Shameless self-promotion here: https://github.com/Hunter-Github/awesome-firefox as a repository of privacy-related links for FF.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of settings and you will find a lot of collections of those.

Here's another shameless self-promotion, but i think it will really help you: https://ffprofile.com
The site guides you through different settings and after deciding what you want to disable, you get a generated config-file and possibly some addons.

The project is linked there and everyone can and should suggest new settings on github. There is a whole category for stuff like this, called "firefox tracking" (in constrast to "website tracking").